# R_TRIG, F_TRIG and TOF not working correctly

Tags: plc, codesys

I have VARs declared

```
trigger_pos_sensor_left                 : BOOL;

trigger_ticks                           :   INT := 0;
trigger_sensor_rtrig                    :   R_TRIG;
trigger_sensor_ftrig                    :   F_TRIG;
delay_timer                             :   TOF;
```

Program is :

```
IF (re = FALSE )THEN
    trigger_sensor_rtrig(CLK := trigger_pos_sensor_left);
    trigger_sensor_ftrig(CLK := trigger_pos_sensor_left);
    delay_timer(IN := trigger_sensor_ftrig.Q, PT := T#10s);
    trigger_ticks := 5;

    re := TRUE;
END_IF

IF (trigger_sensor_rtrig.Q = TRUE) AND (delay_timer.Q = OFF) THEN
    trigger_ticks := trigger_ticks - 1;
END_IF
```

If I understand it correctly r_trig, f_trig and tof are set and "activated" in the first IF and then everytime trigger_pos_sensor_left is activated it should activate set trigger_sensor_rtrig.Q to true and then decrement trigger_ticks by one.
It actually does nothing. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "activated" you mean that they will execute the preset logic without you touching, then **NO**, you **must execute the Function Block on every cycle for it to** ***update*** **the state**.

Let's check the example in the [documentation for R_TRIG](https://content.helpme-codesys.com/en/libs/Standard/Current/Trigger/R_TRIG.html):

```pascal
(* Example declaration *)
RTRIGInst : R_TRIG ;

(* Example in ST *)
RTRIGInst(CLK := VarBOOL1);
VarBOOL2 := RTRIGInst.Q;
```

Notice that the `RTRIGInst(CLK := VarBOOL1);` line is **NOT** enclosed in an if statement, it is executed on every cycle.

Perhaps it would help you understand if we created our own `R_TRIG` block to show how it *probably* works under the hood:

```pascal
FUNCTION_BLOCK R_TRIG
  VAR_IN
    CLK: BOOL;
  VAR_END
  VAR_OUT
    Q: BOOL;
  VAT_END
  VAR
    _first_run: BOOL := TRUE;
    _last_clk: BOOL;
  VAR_END

// implementation:
  IF _first_run THEN
    _first_run := FALSE;
    _last_clk := CLK; // this is so Q isn't set if the initial CLK value was TRUE
  END_IF
  
  Q := FALSE;
  
  IF _last_clk <> CLK THEN
    _last_clk := CLK;
    Q := CLK;
  END_IF

FUNCTION_BLOCK_END
```

As you can see in *my reference* implementation, the edge detection happens inside the Function Block, which is **only executed when the Function Block is run**. Hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 3):

The blocks must be processed at every cycle of the program, remove them from the IF. The way it is, the blocks are not executed by the program.

```
trigger_sensor_rtrig(CLK := trigger_pos_sensor_left);
trigger_sensor_ftrig(CLK := trigger_pos_sensor_left);
delay_timer(IN := trigger_sensor_ftrig.Q, PT := T#10s);

IF (re = FALSE )THEN
    trigger_ticks := 5;
    re := TRUE;
END_IF

IF (trigger_sensor_rtrig.Q = TRUE) AND (delay_timer.Q = FALSE) THEN
    trigger_ticks := trigger_ticks - 1;
END_IF
```